# What is the best way to secure microservices application?

Tags: security, spring-security, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am creating an application based on the microservices architecture. The frontend is written in Angular, the backend consists of a Spring Cloud Gateway, a Spring Boot authorizing microservice (with users in MongoDB) that creates a session stored in the Redis database, several Spring Boot microservices with buisness logic, and a database. I wonder how I should secure my application so that everything complies with the current security trends in this technology stack.

Currently, each microservice has access to the Redis database and returns data if it finds user sessions there. The gateway forwards all queries without checking anything. My security is based on Session Cookie. Everything works but I would like the design to be architecturally correct and I am considering a change. I was thinking about adding authentication only in the gate.

What do you think would be the best way to do this other than what I have mentioned? I was also thinking about whether a session cookie is definitely a good choice.

Comment: Spring security works with Spring Cloud gateway. Gateway is just a boot app

Comment: Nice, thanks. What with my architecture? Any advice?

Comment: One suggestion - Only Frontend, API Gateway and Authentication service should have public URL. All other services should have private ip.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) - The question, as stated, does not meet the community guidelines, please read our [ask] page and come back to [edit] the question to fit within those guidelines. Otherwise, it will be voted to be closed by the community